# Does installing Anaconda result in using up space if I have already installed most of my necessary packages?

Tags: ubuntu, python, anaconda

I want to install Anaconda in ubuntu 18.04 but I have already installed a lot of packages(numpy, numba, scipy, pymc etc) I need. So my question is that does this mean that installing Anaconda results in a lot of common packages getting installed twice ? Should I uninstall the packages I installed first to avoid wasting space ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've done all of your package installs via the distribution supplied package installation methods, or at least properly notified the distribution supplied package management system of the fact that you've installed those dependencies, installing Anaconda should not install any dependencies additional times - if you already installed the dependency for one thing, that should satisfy everything with that dependency.

That's kind of one of the primary purposes of package management.  That, and making it easy to do upgrades.

For the vast majority of users, this stuff just works.  When it doesn't, it's usually because someone messed up, and it's not too difficult to fix.  You may get a skewed idea of the process because people who have problems with it come to places like SuperUser.com, but people who don't, well, don't, at least not for that.

You should understand my careful speech in my first paragraph is not meant to imply that the process is fraught with potential glitches; it's more that the people who tend to come to me for help have put forth great effort to do things in difficult ways that don't work out well.  For example, if you download source code from someplace other than your distribution's source repository, compiled that, and installed that by copying all of the files where you feel they should, aesthetically speaking, you should expect things may not work as well as if you'd followed the recommended practices.